# Реализация онлайн игры

Tags: php, yii2

Всем добрый вечер, я бы хотела проконсультироваться у опытных разработчиков. Хочу реализовать такую задачу:

Есть 2 фабрики. => баланс из рубля, доллара, серебра и золота. => Нужно чтобы пользователь пополнял баланс в долларах и рублях.. => и если пользователь захочет купить монетки из серебра, то он покупает их за рубли, а если он хочет купить монетки из золота, то он покупает их за доллары, => а уже соответственно за золото и серебро он покупает фабрики… => Если например пользователь захочет купить фабрику за серебро, то (бонус) - автоматическое пополнение баланса в процентах будет выставляться в рубли, а если он захочет купить фабрику за золото, то (бонус) - автоматическое пополнение баланса в процентах будет выставляться в доллары..

Вопрос: с чего мне начать эту реализацию.. и есть ли дока - как можно осуществить это? Кстати хочу это сделать в yii2. Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Начать будет разумно с проработки модели. Определить какие будут сущности у системы (пользователь, кошелек, транзакция, товар, операция обмена и т.п.) и какие у них будут связи. Продумать сценарии использования вашего приложения разными участниками системы (User Stories).

Comment: Думаю для такой игры, справится чистый php и js, без каких либо сторонних библиотек и фреймворков. Сделать языки, валюты, а от них уже делать покупки, обмены, продажи и т. д., команды на то, что  `серебро за рубли`, `золото за доллары` и при нажатии на кнопки или какие-то другие действия, выводить соответствующий результат. По поводу вводов средств в игру, нужно регистрировать магазин по электронным переводам, а тут уже смотреть, что регистрировать и как будет работать.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое.. Буду пробовать экспериментировать.. Но  всё таки хотелось конечно это делать во фреймворке.. Так как этот проект я уже начала делать там.. осталось только реализовать вот то что хочу

Comment: @And советуете плохому. А автору я настоятельно рекомендую использовать* фреймворки, и НИКОГДА не кодить на "голом пхп".

Comment: @Manitikyl Согласна с Вами

Comment: Возможно в такой ситуации есть смысл ввести внутреннюю валюту (кредиты) и продавать объекты (в дальнейшем ведь не только фабрики будут?) только за кредиты. Для обмена валюты, сделать биржу кредитов (брать дополнительно процент за каждую сделку). Если уже есть функционал с золотом и серебром, то сделать биржу для золота и серебра. От двух валют возникает серьезная зависимость, с одной проще работать.